# Undergraduate school affecting acceptance to a prestigious graduate school

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

Currently, I am just about to finish my sophomore year in an undergraduate school studying computer science. I am worried about my current school impacting whether or not I will get in to a prestigious graduate school.

Without giving away too many details, my school is fairly well known and has an undergraduate class size of around 30,000. Also, the school is ranked around the 80s of schools in the US.

My growing ambition and love for computer science has grown greatly during my time here and I would to continue my education at a prestigious graduate school.

As of now, I have a 4.0 GPA and I have been and will be involved  with internships during my summers. If I continue my current path, what are my chances at getting into a top 10 american graduate school?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly

Answer (score 2):

Getting into a good grad school has more to do with demonstrating your potential for being a researcher than the quality of the school you attended as an undergraduate. If you don’t have any evidence of research, it’s unlikely that you’re going to get into a top-10 school. If you have an extensive body of solid research as an undergraduate, it can compensate for weak(ish) grades.

Comment: It may be valuable to add some (extended?) version of the first sentence to the admissions process wiki, as variants on this question seem to be a recurring theme.